# How can I test an unchecked checkbox in Django?

Tags: django, unit-testing, checkbox

So I present a checkbox to the user, as you can see inside my `forms.py` file:

```
class AddFooToBarForm(forms.Form):
    to_original = forms.BooleanField(initial=True,
                                     error_messages={'required':
                                                         "Oh no! How do I fix?"})
    ...
```

Depending on whether the user checks or unchecks that checkbox, I do something different, as you can see inside my `views.py` file:

```
def add_foo_to_bar(request, id):
    ...
    try:
        bar = Bar.objects.get(pk=id)

        if request.method == 'POST': # handle submitted data
            form = AddFooToBarForm(bar, request.POST)
            if form.is_valid(): # good, now create Foo and add to bar
                ...
                to_original = form.cleaned_data['to_original']
                print 'to original is {0}'.format(to_original) # for debugging
                if to_original:
                    # do A
                else:
                    # do B

                ...
```

So I want to test that my site does indeed perform the correct actions, depending on whether the user checks the checkbox or not, inside my `tests.py` file:

```
class FooTest(TestCase):
    ...

    def test_submit_add_to_Bar(self):
        form_data = {
            ...
            'to_original': True,
        }
        response = self.client.post(reverse('add_foo_to_bar', args=(self.bar.id,)),
                                    form_data, follow=True)
        self.assertContains(...) # works

        ...

        form_data['to_original'] = None
        response = self.client.post(reverse('add_foo_to_bar', args=(self.bar.id,)),
                                    form_data, follow=True)
        print response # for debugging purposes
        self.assertContains(...) # doesn't work
```

I've tried

- `del form_data['to_original']` -- this gives me the "Oh no! How do I fix?" error message
- `form_data['to_original'] = None` -- in my view function, I get `True`, so A is done instead of B
- `form_data['to_original'] = False` -- this gives me the "Oh no! How do I fix?" error message once again

So how should I test the user *not* checking the checkbox in Django? (I'm using the latest version, 1.4.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checkbox is not checked, its not present in submitted form. Also, when submitted value is `'on'`.

If you want to make `BooleanField` optional have `required=False` while defining the form field.

[Documentation BooleanField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield).

Comment: Ahhhh thanks! I got it to work by checking for whether `to_original` is a key